# Polymer on-click is double posting

Tags: polymer

I'm wondering if anybody here has had a similar problem with Polymer double posting a form.  My code is very simple, as stated previously, each time I click the button the form is posted twice. I'm using Polymer 05.5

```
<polymer-element name="book-form">
    <template>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input id="title" value="{{title}}" />
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input id="author" value="{{author}}" />
        <label for="image">Image:</label>
        <input id="image" value="{{image}}" />
        <button on-click="{{fireAjax}}">Submit Form</button>
        <core-ajax id="ajax"
                   auto
                   url="http://localhost:45922/api/book"
                   handleAs="json"
                   method="POST"
                   >
        </core-ajax>     
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            fireAjax: function () {
                var data = { image: this.image, author: this.author, title: this.title };
                this.$.ajax.contentType = 'application/json';
                this.$.ajax.body = JSON.stringify(data);
                this.$.ajax.go();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fireAjax function changes the data of the core-ajax. Because auto is on, the ajax call is fired. Then you call `this.$.ajax.go()` so the call is fired again.

Try to remove the `auto` in the core-ajax element.

Comment: Thanks Luc, i actually just figured that out and posted an answer, but I'll accept yours.  I'm not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see what the problem is, the auto property on the form post anytime the url or the parameters change.  If one wants to control when the POST takes place they should remove the auto property from core-ajax.

```
<polymer-element name="book-form">
    <template>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input id="title" value="{{title}}" />
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input id="author" value="{{author}}" />
        <label for="image">Image:</label>
        <input id="image" value="{{image}}" />
        <button on-click="{{test}}">Submit Form</button>
        <core-ajax id="ajax"
                   url="http://localhost:45922/api/book"
                   handleAs="json"
                   method="POST"
                   >
        </core-ajax>     
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('book-form', {
            test: function () {
                var data = { image: this.image, author: this.author, title: this.title };
                this.$.ajax.contentType = 'application/json';
                this.$.ajax.body = JSON.stringify(data);
                this.$.ajax.go();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```